In RSpec, how to mock a method so that it returns its argument
Let's say I have a class with a method that modifies and returns a hash.  When testing the class the method will be called, but for the purposes of the test, I want it to return its argument unmodified.
class MyClass 
  def my_method(h)
    # method body that modifies h before returning it
    h.merge!(some_new_key: "some new value")
  end
end

That is, I want to do something like this...
allow(instanceOfMyClass).to receive(:my_method).with( a_hash ).and_return( a_hash )

... where a_hash is an arbitrary hash, not explicitly specified in my test. In the test I want instanceOfMyClass.my_method(a_hash) to return a_hash, the same argument it was passed.
Can this be done in RSpec? If so, how?

Little side note: return is unnessicary here and while ruby will let you write return(...) its not idiomatically correct as return is a keyword and not a method. You can just write h as Ruby implicitly returns the last value. Even better is def my_method(h); h.merge!(some_new_key: "some new value"); end.

Good point!  I've updated the question :)

If you don't need the original implementation at all, you can pass a block implementation to replace the method with:
allow(instance_of_my_class).to receive(:my_method) { |hash| hash }

Or via itself: (which refers to the argument)
allow(instance_of_my_class).to receive(:my_method, &:itself)


You can use and_wrap_original (without actually calling the original) like this:
allow(instance_of_my_class)
  .to receive(:my_method)
  .and_wrap_original { |_method, a_hash| a_hash }


let(:instance) { described_class.new }
let(:value) { { a: 1 } }

before { allow(instance).to receive(:my_method).and_return(value) }

it 'returns hash' do
  expect(instance.my_method).to eq value
end

but this test is very useless

This does not even answer the question or provide any knowledge the asker didn't already have.

question - how to mock method, answer - with before block

The OP wants to mock the method but doesn't want to pass the argument / return value explicitly: "... where a_hash is an arbitrary hash, not explicitly specified in my test.". If you don't know the argument in advance, your solution won't work.
